# bind Dreamweaver for a particular code hint

Tags: php, dreamweaver

I have this function:

```
function Q() {
 return new Q();
}
```

Basically with it I Can do `Q()->methods();`
Without it i couldn't have done it in one line but using the new:

```
$var = new Q();
$var->methods();
```

Now my question is: is there a way to bind the function `Q()` as it was `new Q()` to have the classic code hint displayed?

Note I can referer to a more generic bind (consider I am using a Registry Pattern/Service Container), example:

```
function Q($which) {
 if ($which==1)
  return new FirstObj();
 else
  return new SecondObj();
}

Q(1)->firstClassMethod();
Q(2)->secondClassMethod();
Q('otherClass')->otherClassMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no, you won't get code hints from Dreamweaver for this type of code. Dreamweaver does not execute the PHP code in order to determine what code hints to provide, as it would need to do for this type of "dynamic" object creation especially once you get to objects that themselves have different methods exposed based on what is passed into their constructors (think mixins).

Comment: I think there are some configuration file (maybe xml) where you can manually add a rule and assign 'xyz string' to an Object. I could be wrong

Comment: Technically, yes, you can manually add your own code hints, but it's not documented well, but even if you do figure it out, it would quite likely be hardcoded object names as well as method names. Unless you're using the same objects many many many times, it probably isn't work it. Plus you can make snippets for code chunks you're using all the time.